# 500 internal server error while ajax get request in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

> in route file

```
Route::get('griev_reg_form/assembly/{district_id}', 'GrievanceRegisterController@assembly');
```

> In controller

```
public function assembly($id){
     $assemblyConstituency = AssemblyConstituency::where('dis_code', '=', $id)->orderBy(3)->get();
        $options = array();

        foreach ($assemblyConstituency as $assembly) {
            $options += array($assembly->ac_code => $assembly->ac_name);
        }

        return Response::json($options);
    }
```

In view file

```
   $("#district").change(function() {
            $.getJSON("griev_reg_form/assembly/" + $("#district").val(), function(data) {
                var $assembly = $("#ac_problem");
                $assembly.empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    $assembly.append('<option value="' + index +'">' + value + '</option>');
                });
           // $("#station_id").trigger("change"); /* trigger next drop down list not in the example */
            });
        });
```

> when i change the select box there is error name "HTTP500: SERVER
>   ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented
>   it from fulfilling the request."

Comment: have you checked your error logs? what is in the error log and the access log?

Comment: can you please tell me where i can see that?

Comment: storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: what is you're environment like? windows? linux?

Comment: [2017-04-06 07:38:02] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laranew\app\Http\Controllers\GrievanceRegisterController.php:72
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Comment: This is the error log.. am using windows

Comment: 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' is not being found, look at file `C:\xampp\htdocs\laranew\app\Http\Controllers\GrievanceRegist‌​erController.php` on line `72` to make sure it's valid syntax (symphony)

Answer (score 1):

It is because I didn't add response in the controller

```
use Response;
```